# G++ Compiler bug with compiling variadic function?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw-w64

I have encountered a very weird issue when trying to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>



struct A
{
    int get()
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

static void requestWork(A& program,size_t bytes)
{

}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
static void requestWork( A& program,size_t bytes,T t1, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << t1 << "\n";
    if (program.get() == bytes)
    {
        requestWork(program,bytes + sizeof(t1),args...); 
    }
    else
    {
        requestWork(program,bytes + sizeof(t1), args...); //this line gets complaints
    }
}
int main(int args, char* argsc[])
{
    A a;
    requestWork(a,0,0,0,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't actually do anything; it's a simplified version of some code I had written previously. For some reason, I get an error on the first requestWork recursive call:

`recursively required from 'void requestWork(A&, size_t, T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, int}; size_t = long long unsigned int]'`

I can't find anything online about this error and the weirdest part is that my code compiles fine; if I press build + run again (my IDE was Code::Blocks, I then migrated to CodeLite and ran into the same issue) the code runs fine. Anyone know anything about this?

I initially thought it was Code::Blocks being weird again but upon switching to CodeLite, I ran into the same issue, so I'm fairly certain it's a compiler issue. I'm using g++ 12.2.0. It came with my installation of Mingw-w64.

Comment: Clean compile with a few cosmetic changes for warnings (unused parameters, signed vs unsigned compare) - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3YbG64fez

Comment: `I get an error on the first requestWork recursive call:` this is not the error, this is context. Please show us the __full__ error message.

Comment: I believe that's part of a warning.

Comment: @tkausl I did post the full error, in the very next sentence.

Comment: This is __not__ the full error message.

Comment: Full message - live - https://godbolt.org/z/E7YrPsj3K it's the signed vs unsigned compare.  If you `if (static_cast<size_t>(program.get()) == bytes)` it will suppress the warning.

Comment: It's almost *never* a "compiler bug". In 99.9% of cases it's a bug in the code *you* wrote. Often triggering [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @RichardCritten that's weird, why would it give me an error on my recursive function call then?

Comment: @tkausl it is tho. Is there a specific part you want to see? Because that really is all Code::Blocks is printing out